# Is $\textsf{BPIT}$ equivalent to some ordering principle?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, axiom-of-choice

Working in $\mathsf{ZF}$, is $\mathsf{BPIT}$ (Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem) equivalent to some statement of the form "every set can be ***ly ordered"? I know that $\mathsf{BPIT}$ implies that every set can be linearly ordered, but it does not imply that every set can be well-ordered (because $\mathsf{BPIT}$ is strictly weaker than $\mathsf{AC}$).

Comment: I wrote an answer about this before. Let me find it...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Believe me, I did my homework, and searched thoroughly across the questions involving $\mathsf{BPIT}$. I will wait, though, thanks!

Comment: Okay, it's *almost* an answer to the question. But the reference I give there might do the trick. Let me know... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311246/does-linear-ordering-need-the-axiom-of-choice/311301#311301

Comment: So? Was the reference helpful?

Comment: @AsafKaragila It was, thanks. The author of the paper in the reference is working under $\mathsf{ZF+BPIT}$, though, so I think that this doesn't answer my question exactly.

Comment: Well, it kinda does. Because it shows that any reasonable "...ly ordered" statement is still not provable in ZF+BPI. Add to this that "Every partial order can be extended to a linear order" is strictly weaker than BPIT and you're about done.

Comment: I know that you are plenty of "MSECoins", but if you put this as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

First of all, $\sf BPIT$ is strictly stronger than "every set can be linearly ordered", it is even stronger than "every partial order can be extended to a linear order".

Secondly, in the paper

> *David Pincus*, [**The dense linear ordering principle**](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2275540), *J. Symbolic Logic* **62** (1997), no. 2, 438--456. MR 1464107

the author proves that the following implications are irreversible, even if we assume $\sf BPIT$:

1. Every set can be well-ordered.
2. Every set can be injectively mapped into a power set of an ordinal (which is densely ordered by the lexicographic ordering).
3. Every set can be densely ordered.
4. Every set can be linearly ordered.

It follows, if so, that $\sf BPIT$ is too strong and too weak to be equivalent to any reasonable "Every set can be ***ly ordered".