# Set of elements of an idempotent semirings are totally ordered.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, relations, idempotents, semiring

An element $S$ is said to be totally ordered set if for all $a, b\in S\implies$ either $a\leq b$ or $b\leq a.$

An algebraic structure $(S, +, \cdot)$ is said to be an idempotent semiring if $x\cdot x=x$ for all $x\in S$. Note that $S$ is addively idempotent semiring if $x+x=x$ for all $x\in S$.

In view of the above definitions, can we confirm that

> a set of elements of an idempotent semirings are totally ordered.

Comment: Without specifying some relation between the group operation and the order, this is equivalent to 'can all sets be totally ordered?' which is at least implied by choice, and might be equivalent to it.

Comment: @user24142:  So it is not known if AC is equivalent to "every set is linearly orderable"? AC is equivalent to "every set is well orderable"?

Comment: The answer to my second question is easily yes. The first question is discussed, for example, here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311246/does-linear-ordering-need-the-axiom-of-choice

Answer (score 2):

Your definition of "totally ordered" semiring  and your definition of a semiring are wrong. Assuming the standard [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring), the answer is "no": every bounded, distributive lattice is a commutative, idempotent semiring under join and meet with $1=$ the maximal element and $0=$ the minimal element.